# Are there any benefits on using class constants instead of global constants?

Tags: php, class, constants

Class constant

```
class Hello{    
  const SOME_SETTING = 5;

}
```

Normal constants

```
define('HELLO_SOME_SETTING', 5);
```

To access the class constant I have to call

```
Hello::SOME_SETTING
```

To access the normal constant

```
HELLO_SOME_SETTING
```

So far both are ok, but what happens if I want to update the value of some constants? I would have to browse .php files, track down each class and modify the constants.

But using normal constants I would just place all defines inside a single config file or something, where I can easily find them when I need to change something.

This is one disadvantage of class constants in my opinion. Are there any advantages?

Comment: Same question as "why should I use namespaces?"... Same answer: to not pollute the global namespace. So the most elegant solution would be to use a constant _inside_ a namespace, not inside a class (though that might also make sense).

Answer (score 7):

The main advantage is locality, which affords better organizational structure. If you have a class `BufferedReader` that uses a `BUFFER_SIZE` constant, it's much better for the constant to be defined alongside the code that uses it.

> But using normal constants I would just place all defines inside a
>   single config file or something, where I can easily find them when I
>   need to change something.

That's IMHO the wrong way to use constants (although this practice is quite widespread). A constant is something that, as far as can be foreseen, will not change -- for example, the number of days in a week. What you are describing here is a *configuration variable*.

Comment: Thanks, the locality is a good reason. But you kind of have to sacrifice maintainability for it (is it worth it?). The other part of you answer doesn't make sense. What do you mean a class constant will not change? What's the point of using constant then, and not hardcoding the value directly in the code? Of couse that it may change... All constants are "configuration variables", but a special config variable, of low-level type. I may want to change the `BUFFER_SIZE` value from your example, if I upgrade the server with more memory

Comment: The point is to have it defined in only one place. If you need to change it - you still can. If you need it to be externally configurable - it's not a constant.

Comment: @thelolcat: Suppose you have the constants `HTTP_CODE_NOT_FOUND` and `DB_PASSWORD`. I 'm saying that one of them is more "constant" than the other, and that the password should not be made a constant. Doing that places undue restrictions on your implementation -- e.g. what if you have unit tests that use a different database connection instead? Think about the implications.

Comment: Unit tests shouldn't use a database connection anyway, they should mock the db request/response

Comment: @MarkBaker: Sure, not the best example, but you get the picture.

Comment: So you're saying there are 2 type of constants: state constants and configuration "variables" (like your `BUFFER_SIZE`). Yes it makes sense to put the state constants inside the class, but I still think that the ones which are used for low-level configuration should go inside a single file for easy maintainability, locality is less important in my opinion :P

Comment: @thelolcat: Stuff that only affects low-level mechanisms should not be visible at a high level, just as you don't make a function work on global variables even though it's possible. Of course if you have a different opinion I can't really make you change it. :)